# How to tell which mouse button has been released on MotionEvent.ACTION_UP

Tags: android

I have a mouse connected to my Android 6.0 tablet. I'm trying to listen to left and right mouse pressed and released events in my `onTouch`. It works fine when pressing mouse buttons, but when releasing mouse buttons `getButtonState()` always returns 0 so I cannot tell which button (left or right?) has been released.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if(event.getSource() == InputDevice.SOURCE_MOUSE) {

        int action = event.getActionMasked();   
        int mouseButton = event.getButtonState();

        Log.v("Test", "Action: " + action + " MouseButton: " + mouseButton);            
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

When `Action` is 1 (i.e. `ACTION_UP`), `mouseButton` is always 0 so I cannot tell if the left or right mouse button has just been released. When `Action` is 0 (i.e. `ACTION_DOWN`), `mouseButton` is correctly set to `BUTTON_PRIMARY` or `BUTTON_SECONDARY`.

So does anybody have an idea how to distinguish between left and right mouse button releases on `ACTION_UP`?

Comment: What does `isButtonPressed()` return, for these two buttons, when you get the `ACTION_UP` event? My guess is that you'll get `false` for both, but it's worth a try. Otherwise, I think you have to assume that the `ACTION_UP` is for a previous `ACTION_DOWN` and whatever button that was.

Comment: Yes, `isButtonPressed()` returns `false` for both buttons on `ACTION_UP` but I think I could still use it to identify the button that has been released because `isButtonPressed()` can tell me if a button is still down, i.e. suppose the left button goes down, and then right button goes down and then the left button goes up again while the right button is still down. I can guess that the `ACTION_UP` belongs to the left button because `isButtonPressed()` tells me that the right button is still down. AFAICS it should be possible to make an educated guess then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer my own question, `isButtonPressed()` is the key to this problem. By monitoring `isButtonPressed()` and caching its result whenever you get a MotionEvent from `InputDevice.SOURCE_MOUSE` you can tell which button has been pressed or released. You also need to be careful *not* to limit those observations to `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_DOWN` because when one button is already down and another one is pressed or released, you won't get `ACTION_DOWN` or `ACTION_UP` for it but an `ACTION_MOVE` event will be generated as soon as there's already one button down.

So in terms of code, a solution could look like this:

```
private static boolean mLeftDown = false, mRightDown = false, mMiddleDown = false;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if(event.getSource() == InputDevice.SOURCE_MOUSE) {

            boolean leftDown = event.isButtonPressed(MotionEvent.BUTTON_PRIMARY);
            boolean rightDown = event.isButtonPressed(MotionEvent.BUTTON_SECONDARY);
            boolean middleDown = event.isButtonPressed(MotionEvent.BUTTON_TERTIARY);

            if(leftDown != mLeftDown) {
                // left button pressed or released
                mLeftDown = leftDown;
            }

            if(rightDown != mRightDown) {
                // right button pressed or released
                mRightDown = rightDown;
            }                   

            if(middleDown != mMiddleDown) {
                // middle button pressed or released
                mMiddleDown = middleDown;
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
}
```

This works fine on Android 6.0.

Comment: This works on SOME devices. It depends on driver. Some devices (tested on Android 9 phones) won't send right mouse button, but treat it as back key.